# Where do I find old version of deb files?

Tags: apt, deb

I need to install libhdf5 on an **offline** computer which has Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS installed.

One of the packages it looks for when running `sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev hdf5-tools`

is `libjpeg-turbo8-dev_1.5.2-0ubuntu5.18.04.1_arm64.deb` which "should" be located in http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/libj/libjpeg-turbo/

but I can only find there, the newer, `libjpeg-turbo8-dev_1.5.2-0ubuntu5.18.04.3_arm64.deb`
where can I find the older deb file?

Assume that I can't run `sudo apt-get update` since the computer can't be connected to the web

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Have you tried installing the newer version? Have you got any problems with it? New versions in stable releases like 18.04 should provide mostly bugfixes and should never break compatibility, so you can most likely work with the newer version. To upgrade an offline computer, see [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Comment: No, I have not. I am trying to go "by the book" and look for the exact file. is there a repository for older versions?

Comment: No guaranty that old packages are saved. Please run : Google, libjpeg-turbo8-dev_1.5.2-0ubuntu5.18.04.1_arm64.deb https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=libjpeg-turbo8-dev_1.5.2-0ubuntu5.18.04.1_arm64.deb ... to look for "saved". ... Example hit http://turul.canonical.com/pool/main/libj/libjpeg-turbo/

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/allpackages Search for: libjpeg-turbo8-dev Is listed at the bottom is the version 1.4.2

Comment: _“I am trying to go "by the book" and look for the exact file.”_ I don’t find this a good approach. Software evolves much faster than books do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a histroy of all builds, e.g. for virtualbox:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/6.1.18-dfsg-5/+build/21372864

so for libjpeg-turbo8-dev_1.5.2-0ubuntu5.18.04.1

it will be something like

[https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libjpeg-turbo8/dev_1.5.2-0ubuntu5.18.04.1/+build/[XXXXX]](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libjpeg-turbo8/dev_1.5.2-0ubuntu5.18.04.1/+build/%5BXXXXX%5D) where you have to find out the XXXXX

Comment: @bennyk can you provide the complete link please? jic somone searches for this